# Retrieving tokens while taking quotes and escape characters into account

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node script that reads lines of input from a file where each line is formatted like this:

```
https://youtu.be/hdA_rpOXFws Ouroboros\ ~Infinite\ Circulation~ "Ouroboros ~Infinite Circulation~" VOEZ DLight
...
...
...
```

I want to split these lines into tokens such that the first token will be `https://youtu.be/hdA_rpOXFws`, then `Ouroboros ~Infinite Circulation~`, then `Ouroboros ~Infinite Circulation~`, then `VOEZ`, then `DLight`. Currently my solution revolves around manually going through and checking each space to see if the character is escaped or if there is a quote after it and manually finding the next quote but making sure it's not escaped, but this is headache-inducing. Is there an easy built-in way to do this?

As for why I'm doing this, yes

Comment: Try this regular expression `/(?<=\s|^)(".+"|(\\\s|\S)+)(?=\s|$)/g`. Or use some proper tokenizer library.